# Can dataflow compile code for GPU

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Since dataflow already creates a highly parallel framework, I was wondering if there was anyway to get our dataflow jobs to just "run" on google GPUs (and ideally a cluster of GPUs on different nodes) instead of a cluster of CPUs? It seems like it ought work in a similar manner to how tensorflow does it....

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc: _"Dataflow supports n1series workers as well as custom machine types"_

Comment: So I know that the machine type can have GPUs, but can the dataflow code automatically compile and run on the GPUs instead of CPUs?

Comment: I don't think using GPUs is possible. I can see it is possible with Dataproc (https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/gpu-clusters), but can't see anything for Dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported at the moment, but we are considering it among other features for future prioritization.

Comment: Has there been any movement on this feature request?

Comment: Is Dataflow close to allowing GPUs on workers?  Dataflow is my top choice for a project, but a big piece of the processing relies on GPUs.

Comment: Following up on the two comments above ^^, any movement?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow now provides a preview offering of GPU support, see:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/gpu-support
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-gpus